# Updating State not updating view

Tags: javascript, android, css, react-native

I am currently learning React Native.
I have built a view which should show a text Loading when the data is being fetched and should display the data once the data has been received by the app.
The app is hitting the backend server and is getting the URL(tried console.error on app and it does popup with ared screen showing the correct data details ).

The problem is the view is not being updated.  Another thing that is weird is that the conditional view is showing the border which has been set for the container, but it does not display any text or data except that. Even if I put the correct data. Not sure if the condition is being validated correctly or not.

The border I mentioned is set in articleContainer in the stylesheet and is attached with the container which is with the condition **this.state.hasResult**

If i remove the style from that view the border dissappears obviously but even putting a static text inside the view is not being displayed(checked incase I parsed the json wrong.) Seems a bit confusing.

```
var constants = require("../constants")

var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var t = require('tcomb-form-native');

var authenticate = require("../services/authenticate")

var {
  AppRegistry,
  AsyncStorage,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert,
  ListView,
  Image,
} = ReactNative;

const options = {}

class RecipePage extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id});

    var getData = require("../services/get_featured");

    var par = this;

    var recipeId = props.recipeId;

    this.state ={
          hasResult: false,
          noResult: false,
          result: null,
          isLoading: true,
      }

    getData(recipeId).then(function(data){
        par.setState(
            {
                result:data,
                hasResult:true,
                noResult:false,
                isLoading:false
            }

        )
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
  }

  goBack(){
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Recipe</Text>

          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.goBack.bind(this)}>
              <Image style={styles.back}
                  source={require("../static/images/back.png")}
              />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>

        {
          this.state.hasResult &&

          <View style={styles.article_container} >
              <Text style={styles.article_title} >{this.state.result.id}</Text>

              <Image style={styles.article_img}
                  source={{uri: this.state.result.image_link}}
              />
          </View>
        }

        {
          this.state.isLoading &&

          <View style={styles.article_container} >
              <Text style={styles.article_title} >Loading</Text>
          </View>
        }

        </View>

    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 25,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 30,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginBottom: 30
  },
  article_container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 5,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderBottomColor: '#555555',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    flex:1
  },
  article_title: {
    fontSize: 25,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginBottom: 3,
    flex:2
  },
  article_img: {
      width:200,
      height:200,
      alignSelf: 'center',
      flex:1
  },
  article_description :{
    fontSize:15,
    flex:3
  },

  back:{
    backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
    width:20,
    height:20

  }

});

module.exports =  RecipePage;
```

If you think I can improve the code not relating to this question, then feel free to comment and enlighten me :)

**Edit:**

I played around a bit more and found that if I change the attached styles as:-

```
<View style={styles.row} >
              <Text style={styles.title} >{this.state.result.title}</Text>

              <Image 
                  source={{uri: this.state.result.image_link}}
              />
          </View>
```

from

```
<View style={styles.article_container} >
              <Text style={styles.article_title} >{this.state.result.id}</Text>

              <Image style={styles.article_img}
                  source={{uri: this.state.result.image_link}}
              />
          </View>
```

I am able to view the title after making this change, but image is still not displayed. And I am not sure why it was not showing for the other style.
Even if one of the style is attached -> article_title or article_container, its not being displayed.

**Edit 2:**

Even if I apply the style manually, it is not displayed like

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 25,alignSelf: 'center',marginBottom: 3,flex:2}} >{this.state.result.title}</Text>
```

I am navigating to this page from a parent which uses similar styles for a listview and it is showing there perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that I used **flex** property in styles without using ScrollView or ListView.
I would research more into that and update the answer.